# Define factors whose levels depend on another variable

Tags: r, dataframe

Be this mock data:

```
set.seed(20120220)
x  <- c(rep("a", 4), rep("b", 4))
y  <- c(sample(c(1, 2), 8, replace = TRUE))
z  <- data.frame(cbind(x, y))
```

Data frame `z` will look like this:

```
  x y
1 a 1
2 a 1
3 a 1
4 a 2
5 b 2
6 b 1
7 b 2
8 b 2
```

I want to run something akin to `factor(z$y, levels = 1:2, labels = c("alpha", "beta"))`, but I don't want every `1` to become `alpha` and every `2` to become `beta`. I want that to happen *only* for `x = a`. If `x = b`, I want `1` to become `gamma` and `2` to become `delta`.

In other words, I want my data frame to look like this:

```
  x y
1 a alpha
2 a alpha
3 a alpha
4 a beta
5 b delta
6 b gamma
7 b delta
8 b delta
```

This is what I came up with so far:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(z)) {
  if (z$x[i] == "a") 
    z$y[i] <- factor(z$y[i], levels = 1:2, labels = c("alpha", "beta"))
  else
    z$y[i] <- factor(z$y[i], levels = 1:2, labels = c("gamma", "delta"))
}
```

But it gives me several warning messages (one for each `i`) like this:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L,  :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
```

And then, when I call `z` again, the data frame is a mess, every `y` has been made into `<NA>`.

I bet there's a simple solution for this, but I've been trying several approaches for *hours* to no avail. My head is about to explode! Help!

Comment: Can't you simply add a new column of factors with levels 1:4 and labels 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta' ? It has no sense (and I doubt is possible) to have factors with 2 levels but 4 labels...

Comment: I could do this on a small data set such as the one above, but my actual problem has a few thousand lines, making the approach impracticable.

Comment: have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
> z$ynew <- ifelse(z$x == "a", ifelse( z$y==1, "alpha", "beta"),
                                ifelse(z$y==1, "delta", "gamma") )
> z
  x y  ynew
1 a 1 alpha
2 a 1 alpha
3 a 1 alpha
4 a 2  beta
5 b 2 gamma
6 b 1 delta
7 b 2 gamma
8 b 2 gamma
```

(I guess I swapped your delta's and gamma's. If you want 'ynew' to be a factor then just:  `z$ynew <- factor(z$ynew)`

Comment: This does word, but my actual `y` vector has eight levels, so `ifelse()` wouldn't work. Unless I nested eight ifelses one into the other, which is just too much for me. Is there any wat around this case?

Comment: Probably ... supply a more realistic problem description and example.

Answer (score 1):

What about using merge ?

```
# define x and y   to   'alpha', 'beta' etc.   correspondences 
# (it's just one row for each possible factor)
auxDf <- data.frame( x  = c('a',     'a',    'b',     'b'    ),
                     y  = c( 1,       2,      1,       2     ),
                    newy= c('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta'))

# merge the 2 data.frame getting a new data.frame with the factors column
newDf <- merge(z,auxDf) 
newDf
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but this would require recreating all vectors, right? How could one make this work on a big dataset?

Comment: @wleoncio: Also creating 2 subsets each big 1/2 of the previous data.frame's, creates the same amount of variables :) Are you having memory issues ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one additional step to make the previous answer even a bit quicker - 
you can use 'unique' to pull out all the unique combinations in a data frame.

```
auxDf=unique(z)
auxDf$newy=c('alpha','beta','gamma','delta')
```

Then, as in the previous post

```
newDf <- merge(z,auxDf) 
newDf
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Jennie! Please consider editing digEmAll's answer and inserting your additional step there; that way, we can have all related steps together. SO's answer are dynamically ordered, so referring to "the previous answer" may not work every time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to come up with a solution that works, even though it is quite messy.

First, create subsets of the data frame `z` for each `x`

```
z1 <- subset(z, x == "a")
z2 <- subset(z, x == "b")
```

Then, apply `factor()` to each subset:

```
z1$y <- factor(z1$y, levels = 1:2, labels = c("alpha", "beta"))
z2$y <- factor(z2$y, levels = 1:2, labels = c("gamma", "delta"))
```

And finally, reunite the subsets into the original object.

```
z <- rbind(z1, z2)
```

Comment: I don't see why do you prefer this approach to @DWin solution or the others proposed; they give basically the same results and with this approach in case of many conditions (i.e. 'a', 'b', 'c' ...) you need to perform a lot of subsets...

Comment: You're right, this is just another way to solve the problem. It's just that working with subsets looks less overwhelming to me than with nested ifelses. Now, I do prefer this or DWin's solution to the others, because they work on imported data frames (your suggestion involved recreating every variable, right?).